# Laravel FormRequest with variables

Tags: laravel, validation

How do I put my validation logic within a FormRequest, knowing that my validation rules need variables set by the controller?

```php
    public function store()
    {
        $commentable = Comment::getCommentable(request('input1'), request('input1'));
        // I need this $commentable above in my validator below!

        $this->validate(request(),[
            'commentable_type' => 'required|string|alpha', // Post
            'commentable_id' => 'required|uuid|exists:' . plural_from_model($commentable) . ',' . $commentable->getKeyName(),
            'body' => 'required|string|min:1',
        ]);

        // ...
    }
```

Here is my actual code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKguO.png

I want to tidy up my controller's store() method, moving the validate() in a FormRequest. However, as you can see, it needs the $commentable variable, which is retrieved by the controller.

I guess I could make it so that the FormRequest could retrieve that variable itself as well, but that would be an ugly duplicate (since it would also probe the database twice...). So that is not a good solution at all.

Any idea? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your FormRequest class can do pre-validation steps (including adding/modifying the input data, as shown below) via the `prepareForValidation` hook:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->commentable = Comment::getCommentable($this->input('input1'), $this->input('input1'));

    $this->merge([
        'commentable_id' => $this->commentable->id,
        'commentable_type' => $this->commentable->type
    ]);
}
```

You'll be able to use `$this->commentable` in your `rules()` function, as well.

Comment: Can I return a Response within that prepareForValidation() method so that it kind of "aborts" if my getCommentable() throws an exception? My IDE is complaining about not always having a "return" statement. https://i.imgur.com/OTHl8lh.png

Comment: @13h50 I don't think returning a response will do anything, but you can just `return;` at the end to help the IDE out. An exception in `getCommentable` should float up to the regular exception handler.